# Getting Azure virtual network routing information using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to generate a report that will display azure virtual network routing information. I have a script that gets this information, however the way the information is retrieved needs to be improved.

The hierarchy is as follows,

vnet >> subnet >> route table >> routes

There can be multiple routes defined for a route table. The problem with the script below is that the routes are joined together in a comma list. It makes it difficult to read the report, what I would like to do is have it such that the report displays one line per route, since a route table can have multiple routes, the rest of the other information remains thesame for every route defined that is `SubscriptionName,ResourceGroupName,VNetName,AddressSpace,SubnetName`.

This is what I have so far.

[image]
I am trying to achieve this
[image]

For the column `RoutedCorrectly`, the rule is that if the `NextHopIpAddress` is `10.14.12.13`
or `10.17.12.13` then the field should report Y if the `NextHopIpAddress`  is of any other value then `RoutedCorrectly` is set to N.

The code so far.

```
$report = @()

$subs = Get-AzSubscription
$file_date_suffix = $((Get-Date).ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss"))
$path = "C:\files\report_$file_date_suffix.csv"

foreach ($Sub in $Subs) {
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name | Out-Null
    
    $vnets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
    foreach ($vnet in $vnets) {
        foreach ($subnet in $vnet.Subnets) {
            $vnetInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
                SubscriptionName    = $Sub.Name
                ResourceGroupName   = $vnet.ResourceGroupName
                VNetName            = $vnet.Name
                AddressSpace        = $vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes -join ','
                SubnetName          = $subnet.Name
                RouteTable          = ""
                RouteName           = ""
                AddressPrefix       = ""
                NextHopType  =        ""
                NextHopIpAddress    = ""
                RoutedCorrectly     = ""
            }

            $subnet_config = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnet.Name -VirtualNetwork $vnet
            # $subnet_config | Format-List
            $RouteTableJson = $subnet_config.RouteTableText | ConvertFrom-Json
            $rt_rg = [regex]::Match($RouteTableJson.ID, '/resourceGroups/([^/]+)/').Groups[1].Value


            if ($rt_rg) #only if a route is defined
            {
            $routetables = Get-AzRouteTable -ResourceGroupName $rt_rg
            foreach ($routetable in $routetables) {
                $vnetInfo.RouteTable += $routetable.Name + ","

            }

            $routeConfigurations = Get-AzRouteTable -ResourceGroupName $rt_rg | Get-AzRouteConfig | Select-Object Name, NextHopType, NextHopIpAddress, AddressPrefix
            foreach ($routeConfiguration in $routeConfigurations)
            {
                $vnetInfo.RouteName += $routeConfiguration.Name + ","
                $vnetInfo.AddressPrefix += $routeConfiguration.AddressPrefix + ","
                $vnetInfo.NextHopType += $routeConfiguration.NextHopType + ","
                $vnetInfo.NextHopIpAddress += $routeConfiguration.NextHopIpAddress + ","
                $vnetInfo.RoutedCorrectly +=  ""


            }

        }

        else{

            $vnetInfo.RouteTable += "Undefined"

        }

        $vnetInfo.RouteTable = $vnetInfo.RouteTable.TrimEnd(',')

            $report += $vnetInfo
        }
    }
}

$report | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried getting Azure virtual network routing information using powershell and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The script works fine, but there are commas separating the routes, which reduces the clarity of the report. To make it better, we should put each route on a different line and include the details of the VNet, subnet, and route table for each line.

**My updated powershell script:**

```
# Gather report data
$report = @()
$subs = Get-AzSubscription
$file_date_suffix = $((Get-Date).ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss"))
$path = "C:\Users\demo.csv"

foreach ($Sub in $Subs) {
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name | Out-Null
    
    $vnets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
    foreach ($vnet in $vnets) {
        foreach ($subnet in $vnet.Subnets) {
            $subnet_config = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnet.Name -VirtualNetwork $vnet
            $RouteTableJson = $subnet_config.RouteTableText | ConvertFrom-Json
            $rt_rg = [regex]::Match($RouteTableJson.ID, '/resourceGroups/([^/]+)/').Groups[1].Value

            if ($rt_rg) {
                $routetables = Get-AzRouteTable -ResourceGroupName $rt_rg
                foreach ($routetable in $routetables) {
                    $routeConfigurations = $routetable | Get-AzRouteConfig
                    foreach ($routeConfiguration in $routeConfigurations) {
                        $routedCorrectly = if ($routeConfiguration.NextHopIpAddress -eq "10.14.12.13" -or $routeConfiguration.NextHopIpAddress -eq "10.17.12.13") {"Y"} else {"N"}
                        $report += [PSCustomObject]@{
                            SubscriptionName    = $Sub.Name
                            ResourceGroupName   = $vnet.ResourceGroupName
                            VNetName            = $vnet.Name
                            AddressSpace        = $vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes -join ','
                            SubnetName          = $subnet.Name
                            RouteTable          = $routetable.Name
                            RouteName           = $routeConfiguration.Name
                            AddressPrefix       = $routeConfiguration.AddressPrefix
                            NextHopType         = $routeConfiguration.NextHopType
                            NextHopIpAddress    = $routeConfiguration.NextHopIpAddress
                            RoutedCorrectly     = $routedCorrectly
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $report += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    SubscriptionName    = $Sub.Name
                    ResourceGroupName   = $vnet.ResourceGroupName
                    VNetName            = $vnet.Name
                    AddressSpace        = $vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes -join ','
                    SubnetName          = $subnet.Name
                    RouteTable          = "Undefined"
                    RouteName           = ""
                    AddressPrefix       = ""
                    NextHopType         = ""
                    NextHopIpAddress    = ""
                    RoutedCorrectly     = ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# Export report to CSV
$report | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

This script should generate a report in the format you have asked for with one route per line

**Output:**

[image]